# inverse Fixed point number (number^-1)

Tags: fixed-point, conversion

Could someone please provide a method for inverting random fixed point numbers.
I have as an input both positive and negative floating point numbers that should be converted into fixed point and then be inverted.

An example could be 1/0.2453 where floating-point 0.2453 is converted into a Q18 fixed point format and then inverted to 4.07664.
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: why the negative vote for?

Comment: given your example, you know that the result would be greater than 1, correct?  in fact, it would be just a little bit greater than 4.  not quite what we might think is "Q18".  so how are you defining your fixed-point numbers?  that's the first thing you have to settle.

Comment: BTW, i know this "Q$nn$" notation is popular with some, but not with me.  may i suggest Q$i$.$f$ where $i$ is the number of integer bits (and the sign bit counts as an integer bit) and $f$ is the number of fractional bits?  then, for coding this thing in C (which does not have a "fixed" numerical type), you need to express an explicit relationship between the fixed-point value (which really exists only in the mind of the programmer) to the integer value (which is what the CPU is aware of).  if you have that scaling relationship down pat, you can figure any of these issues out.

Comment: i reduced your negative votes by 1.  there are enough bad questions on SE that this one exceeds in relevance, that i wonder the same thing (about the negative vote) as you.

Comment: The problem (not well clarified in my description and sorry about that) is that in Q18 format,any number will be massive so that one will get by dividing 1/Q18(number) will be effectively zero.The fixed point number will be then represented by ones and zeros within that 18 bits,were if one tries o convert int decimal will see that it will be a massive number.

Comment: So as an example 1 in Q18 (as i have to deal with) would be 0x00040000 (HEX) that is 262144 in decimal.That means if i wanted to do the 1/1(Q18) would be impossible.So many people use look up tables to cope with similar problems and i would like to ask if you have any simpler idea or if there is any popular and straightforward way to work with such an issue.I know is very practical and with not much interest question but people  bump into many times.Thank you very much for your replies.

Comment: doesn't seem like you're taking me up on my suggestion.  how many bits to the right of the binary point exist in your "Q18" number?  18?  17?  something else?  what is the range of value of your "Q18" numbers?  0 to just under 1 (that is $1-2^{-18}$)?  or from -1 to just under 1 (or $1-2^{-17}$)?

Comment: To the right of the binary point are 18 bits,and the range of values is from 0 to 5 with a step of 0.02 (at least in order to be precise enough)(Sorry for missing that info).But here even if i manage to proceed by using a lookup table i doubt how functional that will be while the size of it is very big.

Comment: your answer is, as best as i can tell, self-contradictory.  if your "Q18" number, $x$, is how i would dub it, a "Q0.18" number, which means 0 bits to the left of the binary point and 18 bits to the right, then the range of values is $0 \le x \le 1-2^{-18} < 1$.  5 is not in that range.  you need to settle this before you start multiplying or dividing numbers.

Comment: hey Paul R, hotpaw2, jojek, lennon310, Naresh:  what's off-topic about this question?  is all DSP done in floating point in your worlds?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: General programming questions belong on stackoverflow, not here, but I think this is DSP-appropriate enough for this site.  I don't think fixed-point is that common in general programming.

Comment: @GiwrgosRizeakos Here's a practical example: http://blog.voltampmedia.com/2011/09/27/using-arms-cmsis-dsp-library-arm_recip_q15/

Comment: @endolith, i personally disagree with the notion that fixed-point arithmetic is off-topic for DSP.  don't agree with it at all.  if you were to count all of the devices in the world doing solely fixed-point DSP and compare that to the number of devices in the world doing floating-point DSP, i think the former is the larger number.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: yes, that's why I voted to reopen it.  I think embedded DSP programmers will be more familiar with fixed point than computer programmers.

Comment: @endolith, okay so i added 1 to the count.

Answer (score 6):

the first thing that one must understand when doing fixed-point arithmetic is that, at the basic level, it is **integer** arithmetic with some scaling factors applied.  perhaps just one scaling factor applied.  this scaling factor is directly related to the position of the binary point.  unless the chip is a fixed-point DSP or similar, the binary point is **implied**, not explicit.  it, and the associated scaling factor, exists only in the mind of the programmer.  the CPU only thinks it is working on integers.

as an example an unsigned, fixed-point, 16-bit format, that i would call "1.15" or, perhaps "Q1.15" (i think the "Q" is superfluous and notation like "Q16" does not supply enough information) has 1 bit to the left of the binary point and 15 bits to the right.  but the 16 bits, sitting all by themselves, is an integer.  the range of that unsigned integer, $n$, is $0 \le n \le 2^{16}-1$.  but the range of the unsigned fixed-point number implied $\hat{n}$ is $0 \le \hat{n} \le 2 - 2^{-15}$ = 1.99996948242188 .

the relationship between the two is:
$$ \hat{n} = n \cdot 2^{-15} $$
or
$$ n = \hat{n} \cdot 2^{15} $$ .

note that the "15"(or "-15") in the exponents is the same as the "15" in the "Q1.15" notation.  the scaling factor is directly related to the number of implied bits to the right of the binary point.

if, instead it was a 16-bit *signed*, we might use "s.15" or "Qs.15" notation to refer to the format, the range of the signed integer $n$ is $-2^{15} \le n \le +2^{15} - 1$.  and the range of the implied fixed-point value, $\hat{n}$, is $-1 \le \hat{n} \le 1 - 2^{-15}$ = 0.99996948242188 .

and the mapping between the two is the same as above:
$$ \hat{n} = n \cdot 2^{-15} $$
or
$$ n = \hat{n} \cdot 2^{15} $$ .

the only difference is the use of `unsigned int` vs. `int` in your C code.  they both have the same number of bits to the right of the binary point and they both have the same mapping.

now when C does addition or subtraction or multiplication or division of these values, it is operating on the **integer** representation of those values.  but the integer representation is the same as your implied value, except for the scaling factors.

so if you want to divide some numerator $\hat{n}$ by some denominator $\hat{d}$ to result in some quotient $\hat{q}$, you must first establish what the ranges of all three numbers are.  then establish how many bits are to the right of the binary point for each number.  then map those numbers $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{d}$ to their integer values $n$ and $d$, and determine what the range of the integer quotient is **before** it is adjusted to represent $\hat{q}$.  there will be a scaling factor that will pop out at you (a power of 2) which will imply shifting of either $n$ or $d$ (most likely $n$) before the integer division is done.